# How to enable Text formats after disabling it in Drupal?

Tags: 7, input-formats

In attempting to get pictures inline with text, I did the following:

`Configuration>> content authoring >> text formats>>` and disabled *Full HTML* and *Filtered HTML* formats.

This clearly did not give me the desired result as now all text is no longer visible on my Drupal website.

How do I re-enable this text on the website?

Comment: This is bug [Disabled text formats can't be seen in the GUI](https://www.drupal.org/node/2502637).

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a bug in Drupal. Anyway the following method works.

1. Go to your Drupal database (I use phpMyAdmin)
2. Browse table called '`filter_format`'
3. There You can see list of input formats.  In  '`status`' column  change
   (update) status form **0** to **1**. (Disabled status will have 0. So
   change to 1 to enable)
4. Clear your cache. (`configuration >> development >> performance`)

That's it. Now  all 'Text formats' will be visible under that configuration page.

It works, I tested it :)

Comment: Great - thank you! How do I get to the Drupal database?

Comment: Don't you have access permission to database? Where is it? It exists in your local system or other environment?

Comment: @Colette - you can find your database settings under /sites/default/settings.php file.

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer, I'm somewhat amazed there isn't a way to do it in the UI.

Comment: Here it comes as a handy drush command `drush sql-query "UPDATE filter_format SET status = '1' WHERE filter_format.format = 'full_html'"`.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following script to update your database:

```
db_update('filter_format')
  ->fields(['status' => 1])
  ->condition('format', 'full_html')
  ->execute();
```